# I am having trouble of setting my TextVIew in java using android studio

Tags: java, android, textview

My java class is written as

```
public class MusicalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView speedTextView;
private TextView paceTextView;
private TextView calburntTextView;
private RunnerInformation runnerInformation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_musical);

    speedTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed_text_view);
    speedTextView.setText("Current Speed" + "6m/s");

    paceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pace_text_view);
    paceTextView.setText("Current Pace" + "60/min");

    calburntTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calburnt_text_view);
    calburntTextView.setText("Current Calories Burnt" + "1000");
}
}
```

and my xml file is like

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/speed_text_view" />
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/pace_text_view" />
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/calburnt_text_view" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

I try to assign "Current speed 6m/s" to the textView which id is speed_text_view but I get nothing on it. Furthermore, what should I do if I want to assign dynamic text to the textview? The speed is dynamic and is retrieved from the "runnerInformation"

Comment: Only speed_text_view does not work or do all 3 text views stay blank? Try removing the "android:padding" from the xml.

Comment: Can you show the image what exactly it is looking like@William Liu.

Comment: Using 'wrap_content' for both layout size parameters of textview is a bad practice. Sometimes, it can prevent parent from redrawing even if you're setting non-empty text into textview

Answer (score 0):

In xml file, Change linear layout height and width from "**wrap content**" to "**match parent**".

Comment: Thank you for answering that fast.............but it doesn't solve the problem. I still get nothing in my simulator